# Two way binding not working on bootstrap modal angularJs

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Why two way binding is not working with a modal using the same controller?

I have a modal using ng-models that are in the controller, but whenever a change the data on the modal, it will not change in the controller.

Controller:  **createEventController**
Holding the object

```
$scope.newEvent = 
        {
            "name": "",
            "location": "",
            "latitude": "",
            "longitude": ""
            "taxoption": 
                    {
                        "country": "",
             ........
```

View:

Note **ng-model="newEvent.taxoption.country"**

```
<div ng-controller="createEventController" class="modal fade" id="ticketTaxModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="TicketTaxForm">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Tax Options</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: left;">
        <div class="form-horizontal">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="country" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Country</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select id="country" ng-model="newEvent.taxoption.country" class="form-control">
                <option value="CAN">Canada</option>
                <option value="USA">United States</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
..............
```

Modal Directive:

```
directive("ticketTax", [function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/create/ticketTaxModal.html',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){


        }
    }
}]);
```

How to pass the data from the modal to the controller? I don't understand why two way binding is not working since the same controller is assigned to the modal. something with instances?

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is requiring the controller in your directive via adding `require: 'ngModel',` and accessing by adding 4th argument to the link function which holds the controller (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl). I think you need to manually set up the watchers to update your model if you are using such directive for modal (which I wouldn't prefer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it removing the ng-controller in the view. I think it was creating another instance of the controller thus blocking two way binding.